# Could not evaluate cost function using sumBy function in Lodash

Tags: angularjs

I have a function called cost in scope.The Primary task of this function is to fetch arrays, filter it based on the requirement and evaluate the cost of the task.  It has two parameters called tasks and time.While debugging the function, the array of data passes on tasks and it retains in the second line where my loadash `sumBy` function exists. I could not get cost out of it.

```js
$scope.cost = function(tasks, time) {
    return _.sumBy(tasks, function(t) {
        if (t.billable && t[time]) {
            var types = _.filter($scope.taskTypes, function(typ) {
                return (t.type == typ._id);
            });
            return t[time] * types[0].rate;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
};
```

My array has these values.

```
{ 
    billable: true,
    estimatedTime: 6, 
    jobId: 1234,
    label: gh, 
    status: ÄSSIGNED, 
    type: 3D-Modelling,
    _id:08746574687 
}
```

Comment: This is the issue with $scope you didn't injected it seems!

Comment: Can you add full code?

Comment: @Sarah Can you make sure that `$scope.taskTypes` is defined by the time it is accessed and `types` always gets a non-empty array? For us to help you properly you would need to post the controller code.